# Отображение нужного блока по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Имеются кнопки и идущие за ними блоки. У кнопок одинаковый класс и у блоков также. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывался следующий за ней блок.

```
<button class="portfolio_work_btn"></button>
 <div class="site-example"></div>

<button class="portfolio_work_btn"></button>
 <div class="site-example"></div>

<button class="portfolio_work_btn"></button>
 <div class="site-example"></div>

<button class="portfolio_work_btn"></button>
 <div class="site-example"></div>
```

Блоки изначально скрыты display:none;

```
$('.portfolio_work_btn').click(() => {
        $(this)+$('.site-example').show(500);
    });
```

Выводит последний блок. Помогите как выбрать только следующий. Или каждую кнопку именовать своим классом и каждый блок также своим именем, а затем на каждую кнопку вешать CLICK. Заранее спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так. Если брать данную вёрстку которую Вы предоставили. Код на Jquery.

```js
var btns = $('.portfolio_work_btn');
var conts = $('.site-example');

btns.click(function() {
  conts.removeClass('active');
  var content = $(this).next();
  content.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.site-example {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="portfolio_work_btn">1</button>
 <div class="site-example">11</div>

<button class="portfolio_work_btn">2</button>
 <div class="site-example">22</div>

<button class="portfolio_work_btn">3</button>
 <div class="site-example">33</div>

<button class="portfolio_work_btn">4</button>
 <div class="site-example">44</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сильно выручил. Я next() также пробовал, но неправильно. Теперь все заработало.

Comment: @Peps_poos рад помочь)